# Hadith about asking where one is from

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I once heard a hadith that one is discouraged to ask questions like: "Where are you from?" because for whatever reason the other side may be embarrassed to give an answer (and perhaps he will lie because of that).

What is the source of the hadith?

Comment: This sounds a bit strange do you have any additional information?

Comment: @Medi1Saif♦ Regretfully, no. But *I did* search it in general terms in Turkish, and the search results *suggested* that such concept does exist in hadith literature. (Sure enough, I did not find any source.)